# MySQL query on how to subtract the datetime in different rows but same column with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, datetime, subtraction

I have table as below, and I am required to filter by same date and same site before I proceed to calculate the duration of the alarm 3 starts triggering and ends triggering, providing the condition that alarm 3 is always followed by alarm 6 within time gap of maximum 60s for their start time, which means that the time gap for start time of alarm 3 and alarm 6 must be always within 60seconds.

```
site | alarm | start               | end 
-----| ------| --------------------| ------------------- 
A    | 3     | 2020-01-03 22:25:16 | 2020-01-03 22:25:46 
A    | 6     | 2020-01-03 22:25:26 | 2020-01-03 22:35:26
A    | 5     | 2020-01-03 10:25:16 | 2020-01-03 10:26:26
A    | 3     | 2020-01-03 12:25:16 | 2020-01-03 12:26:26 
B    | 3     | 2020-01-04 22:22:16 | 2020-01-04 22:22:59
B    | 6     | 2020-01-04 22:22:40 | 2020-01-04 22:25:26
```

I expect to get the outcome table as below,

```
site | alarm | start               | end                 | duration(seconds)
-----| ------| --------------------| --------------------| --------
A    | 3     | 2020-01-03 22:25:16 | 2020-01-03 22:25:46 | 30
A    | 6     | 2020-01-03 22:25:26 | 2020-01-03 22:35:26 | 
B    | 3     | 2020-01-04 22:22:16 | 2020-01-04 22:22:59 | 43
B    | 6     | 2020-01-04 22:22:40 | 2020-01-04 22:25:26 |
```

Comment: In your outcome for the first row duration the end time '22:25:46 'is not available in your data. Can you explain this?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the mistake, it is corrected and updated. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. This would maybe sort it out :)

```
SELECT * FROM MyTab T WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,open_date,close_date) > 1
```

Comment: Hi, actually the limit of 60s is referring to the start time between alarm 3 and alarm 6. so if their time gap for start time is within 60s, then I can proceed to calculate the time difference between start and end time for alarm 3, while filtering the rest out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Substitute *Alarms* with your table name

```
SELECT 
    site,
    alarm,
    start,
    end,
    CASE
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, START, END) <= 60 THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, START, END)
        ELSE NULL
    END AS duration
FROM
    Alarms
WHERE
    alarm IN (3 , 6)
ORDER BY site,alarm;
```

Comment: Hi, the limit of 60s is actually referring to the start time between alarm 3 and alarm 6 for the same site. so if their time gap for start time is within 60s, then I can proceed to calculate the time difference between start and end time for alarm 3